# Localize iOS app based on iTunes Country

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, itunes, itunes-store

I have an iOS app that will be available in 2 countries (or more). I want to use different API roots and different interface languages, based on iTunes country, not the device language or region.

Fx: My app will be available in Italy and Denmark. If the app is downloaded from the Italian store, it will call "http://it.api.com" and it will be in italian language. If it's downloaded from Danish store, it will call "http://dk.api.com" and it will be in danish language.

Is this thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, I'm afraid.

Submit two different apps with the code pulling from the respective API and limit the app availability to the respective country.